# jQuery will not read value of input within hidden <div>

Tags: jquery, hidden

I have an input -

`<input id="post_name" type="text" value="123" name="post_name">`

This input is contained within a `<div>` that is hidden when the page loads, and jQuery will not retrieve the value of the input -

`var current_name = $('input[name="post_name"]').val();`

I can read the rest of the object, and get attirbutes such as `name` and `id`, but the value is eluding me. Is this a jQuery bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure there is an actual value set in the text input?

Comment: Yes, it's 123 for testing purposes. The code above is copied direct from the source. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check that this function is executed after the DOM has loaded the objects?

Comment: can you please put more code over here.

Comment: How exactly is the DIV hidden? Because the value retrieval works just fine if the DIV is `style="display: none; visibility:hidden;"`.

Comment: @KyorCode - Yep, it's run on `$(document).ready()`. Thanks.

Comment: @AshishGupta - I will post some more shortly.

Comment: Could you edit this to recreate the issue? http://jsfiddle.net/Xv86E/1/

Comment: @DamyanPetev - My understanding is that it shouuld work because the value is in the DOM, regardless of whether or not it is being displayed. I'm using `display: none;`. Thanks.

Comment: @Niklas - No, but your efforts on jsfiddle have let me to the problem. I have a form that pops up when a user clicks 'Save' to ensure that they enter all relevent information, and I stupidly duplicated the ID/name that I am using on the form filed! Changed that, it's fine. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidGard - Thumbs up for solving it =)

Comment: @Niklas - Ha thanks, but surely I get several thumbs down for being foolish enough to have the problem in the first place!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is depressingly simple - I accidently duplicated to ID and name that I was using for the input earlier in my code, so it was that which was being picked up by the jQuery.

The lesson I've learned - don't be a donut! And check your code to ensure that selector IDs and input names are not duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

why  don't you use 'id' to get the values instead of name... i think that shuold work
try this out..

```
//execute this function whn document is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
//get the val from id
var current_name =$('#post_name').val();
alert(current_name); //alert and see if u getting the value.
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the issue. The issue was that I acciednetly duplicated the ID/name of the form filed, so that (empty) one was being grabbed by JS.